# show only specific tabs on page AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to have a common index.html page where it has links to all the template htmls and menu tabs. I want to show only specific tabs depending on the tab the user clicks. Suppose if there are 3 menu bar tabs, 1. login 2. register 3. movies

I want to show the movies tab only when user logs in.

Here's the sample index.html I have.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="movieflix">

<head>
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- vendor:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- app:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
</head>

<body class="main">
<header>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#/movies">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<section ng-view>


</section>

<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- vendor:js -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- app:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
</body>

</html>
```

I tried using controller which checks the user's choice, but that doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your controller code?

Comment: Here's me controller

`(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('TabController', function () {
        this.tab = 1;

        this.setTab = function (tabId) {
            this.tab = tabId;
        };

        this.isSet = function (tabId) {
            return this.tab === tabId;
        };
    });
})();`

Comment: this? You will need to use $scope.tab Please read through Angular docs to refer proper implementation. Angular uses 2 way binding, so You will need to approach this issue differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, create three different flags to show and hide tabs. and update value of that flag as per user choice.

For example,

1. Create one navigation controller for header tag.
2. In that controller create three different flags and assign default value to it.
     `var displayLoginTab=true; var displayRegisterTab=false; displayMovieTab=false;`

Then modify your html as above

`<header ng-controller="navigationController">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-if="displayMovieTab"><a href="#/movies">Movies</a></li>
        <li ng-if="displayLoginTab"><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
        <li ng-if="displayRegisterTab"><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>`

Because we use separate controller for this, from other controller try to access navigation controller variable or update variable from any other controller and broadcast that update. listen that broadcast event in navigationController and update that variable value.

Comment: This is the best answer. Thanks so much. I solved this issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

in order to achieve this u have to use a service for storing the users logged in data, 
After successful login store the data in service as `userData`, and in your controller check if user is logged IN OR NOT by checking `userData`,
then  set `showTab` variable as true or false vice versa,and use this variable in view to show or hide the tab ... 
note: not appending codes ...